# Pandas Multiindex Groupby Aggregation - Multiple Layers

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

I am trying to plot the following data using Plotly, that is stored in a multiindex dataframe:

```
ship_out_df.head(3)
                              out_tonnes    
date        loc     product         
2020-05-01  ABC     AFM       8000
                    PRE       6000
            DEF     PRE       6000
                    BZF       25200
2020-05-02  ABC     AFM       8400  
                    PRE       0 
            DEF     PRE       0 
                    BZF       25700
2020-05-03  ABC     AFM       8000  
                    PRE       8000  
            ABC     PRE       8000  
                    BZF       25000
```

Unfortunately, Plotly cannot handle multiindex dataframes so the records with repeated index values i.e. 'PRE' are not plotted.

How can I get the values to pass to the plotly params that maintains the date/grade structure (I don't need the loc)? i.e. for 'PRE'

```
date          product  out_tonnes
'2020-05-01'  PRE      12000
'2020-05-02'  PRE      0
'2020-05-03'  PRE      16000
```

I have tried:

```
y = ship_out_df.groupby(['product']).get_group('PRE').out_tonnes.values
```

however this of course loses the 'date' structure and counts all values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC ,

```
result = (df.reset_index().loc[lambda x: x['product'].eq('PRE')]
            .groupby(['date','product'], as_index=False)['out_tonnes']
            .sum())
print(result)

         date product  out_tonnes
0  2020-05-01     PRE       12000
1  2020-05-02     PRE           0
2  2020-05-03     PRE       16000
```

Comment: please check now!:)  you can  use `.set_index('date')` at the end 
to put date as the index  or We could use `as_index = True`
if We want have `product` and `date` as index. You are welcome !